# Power on by PCI enabled, but no wake on LAN

Tags: bios, power-management, wake-on-lan

Trying to wake my PC that runs Windows 10 and is based on Asus B85M-E motherboard from LAN.
I did bios configuration `Power ON By PCI-E/PCI - Enabled` :

[image]

Also I have configured network card by this purpose:

`Allow this device to wake the computer` - checked:

[image]

I have used several programs that runs on windows and Android to wake up my PC, but this not helps.

How to solve this problem?

UPD

I was trying to find

```
Power Management, Deep Sleep in bios and turn it off, but couldn't find.
```

`powercfg -a`  brings:

```
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S3)
    Hibernate
    Hybrid Sleep
    Fast Startup

The following sleep states are not available on this system:
    Standby (S1)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Standby (S2)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
```

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://help.logmein.com/articles/en_US/Documentation/central-c-host-preferences-troubleshooting-wol-pc
And this one: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb932199.aspx

Comment: I went through list of recommendations, and updated question body with more details